# Re instantiating a singleton

Tags: java, web-applications, singleton

I am building an online travel portal. I have used a singleton class to store the number of rooms available for a particular hotel.  But if data is updated in database, there is no way to reflect it in the app , without restarting the server (since i am using singleton). Is there any way to do so or am I wrong somewhere? What is the best approach in solving such problems? (I am using the singleton in place of a global variable)

Comment: `Singleton for number of rooms in a hotel!!!` Why would you do so? That seems a forced use of pattern than a logical one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons?rq=1 read these posts which guide you not to use singletons blindly

Comment: Post some code as well.

Comment: Re-instantiating a singleton poses whole lot of thread safety issues. Also if you need to re-instantiate a singleton, that is a begging that it should not be a singleton at the first place.

Comment: since i do not want two users to book a room simultaneously, i preferred singleton. i can synchronize the booking process , but it will have lots of performance overhead

Comment: you will still have to synchronize a singleton too. There are much better techniques available like lock stripping. Dont use a same lock for whole hotel. You can keep **one lock per room**. So that no two users will be able to book same room at the same time.

Comment: Serializating at sever and Deserializating at client side(App) can get you a new singleton object. A hacky way and not recommended but you may try because you have your design constraint.

Comment: @AniketThakur Not if it is an `enum singleton` :P

Comment: No its not an enum singleton . Its a double checked locking. Further two users can book the same room if the room count is two. so one lock per room will not do any help

Comment: A singleton is not necessary to prevent simultaneous booking of the same room.  Synchronization is the best approach for that.  Probably using a `synchronized ( hotelRoom ) { ... }` construct at the point of assigning the "winner" of the room.

Comment: To support the multi-booking, put the counter check and update inside the synchronized block.

Comment: In case of two rooms you will hold lock on two rooms simultaneously :) As simple as that. **No of locks held will be same as no of rooms being booked.** Keep in mind to unlock all the locks when booking is cancelled.